# Unable to instantiate AppiumDriver in perfecto for Mobile Web Browser Testing

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser, appium, qaf, perfecto

We are trying to instantiate Appium driver for Mobile Web Browser Testing for Android and iOS on perfecto. But we are getting "cannot be cast to class" error. Detail is mentioned below:

#### QAF Version

Selenium - 4.11.0
Appium Java-Client - 8.4.0
QAF - 4.0.0-RC2
OpenJDK 17

#### perfecto.properties :

```
driver.name=perfectoRemoteDriver
remote.server=https://.perfectomobile.com/nexperience/perfectomobile/wd/hub/fast
remote.port=80
perfecto.additional.capabilities={"perfecto:options":{"securityToken":"","javascriptEnabled":true,"openDeviceTimeout":5.0, "scriptName":"QAF test","platformName":"iOS","browserName":"Safari","automationName":"Appium"}}
```

#### Steps To Reproduce

Call **new AppiumSteps.getAppiumDriver();**

#### Expected behavior

Should be able to create AppiumDriver based on the platformName

#### Actual behavior

```
class org.openqa.selenium.remote.TracedCommandExecutor cannot be cast to class org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor (org.openqa.selenium.remote.TracedCommandExecutor and org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

#### Is the issue reproducible on runner?

- IntelliJ
- Maven

#### QAF Logs

```
    com.qmetry.qaf.automation.core.AutomationError: Unable to build AppiumDriver from class com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ui.webdriver.QAFExtendedWebDriver
at .Given the user login with credential(scenarios/E2E/e2e.feature:10)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.AppiumSteps.getAppiumDriver(AppiumSteps.java:245)
at cloud.steps.IllustrationVerificationSteps.landsOnTheLoginPage(IllustrationVerificationSteps.java:50)
at cloud.steps.CommonSteps.loginWithCredential(CommonSteps.java:39)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.JavaStep.doExecute(JavaStep.java:150)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.BaseTestStep.execute(BaseTestStep.java:149)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.StringTestStep.execute(StringTestStep.java:128)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.Scenario.execute(Scenario.java:174)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.DataDrivenScenario.scenario(DataDrivenScenario.java:66)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.openqa.selenium.remote.TracedCommandExecutor cannot be cast to class org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor (org.openqa.selenium.remote.TracedCommandExecutor and org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.AppiumSteps.getAppiumDriver(AppiumSteps.java:215)
at cloud.steps.IllustrationVerificationSteps.landsOnTheLoginPage(IllustrationVerificationSteps.java:50)
at cloud.steps.CommonSteps.loginWithCredential(CommonSteps.java:39)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.JavaStep.doExecute(JavaStep.java:150)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.BaseTestStep.execute(BaseTestStep.java:149)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.StringTestStep.execute(StringTestStep.java:128)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.Scenario.execute(Scenario.java:174)
at com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.DataDrivenScenario.scenario(DataDrivenScenario.java:66)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:645)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:851)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1177)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
... 3 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using driver with driver class  instead of remote driver. For example:

```
driver.name=perfectoDriver
remote.server=https://<NAME>.perfectomobile.com/nexperience/perfectomobile/wd/hub/fast
perfecto.additional.capabilities={"driverClass" : "io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver",\
        "perfecto:options":{\
        "securityToken":"<TOKEN>","javascriptEnabled":true,\
        "openDeviceTimeout":5.0, \
        "scriptName":"${current.testcase.name}",\
        "platformName":"iOS","browserName":"Safari","automationName":"Appium"}}
```

Use Android driver class `io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver` for Android